# React Pagination next button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I have problem with my pagination. I want block next page button when records on next page are not exist.

Render:

```
  render() {
    const characters = this.props.contacts;
    const { currentPage, todosPerPage } = this.state;
    const indexOfLastTodo = currentPage * todosPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - todosPerPage;
    const currentTodos = characters.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);

    const renderTodos = currentTodos.map((character, index) => {
      return <div className="col-md-2">
      <img src={character.image} className="img-thumbnail" alt="" />
      <div className="content">
        <h6 className="header">{character.name}</h6>
        <h6 className="header">status: {character.status}</h6>
        <h6 className="header">species: {character.species}</h6>

      </div>
    </div>
    });
    const pageNumbers = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(characters.length / todosPerPage); i++) {
      pageNumbers.push(i);
    }
    const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.map(number => {
      return (
        <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
        <ul className="pagination justify-content-center">
        <li className="page-link"
          key={number}
          id={number}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          {number}

        </li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
      );
    });
  return (
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
      {renderTodos}
      </div>
      </div>
  <ul className="pagination justify-content-center">
    <li onClick={this.decrement} className="page-link">
      <a aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        <span className="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    {renderPageNumbers}
    <li onClick={this.increment} className="page-link">
      <a aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        <span className="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
  );
}
}
export default Pages;
```

In decrement function I create a simple condition but I can't get pageNumbers.length value from render() to increment function.

Is there a other way to resolve this problem?

Comment: How are you finding that there a re no next pages?

Comment: i see it now, You can place your pageNumbers function outside the render method and call it from increamnent to return pagenumber.length?

Comment: I tried this but i have error : 'pageNumbers' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: You should post your whole component here or at least the render, need to know where characters are coming from

Comment: Whole component did not fit but i posted render now

Comment: Added an answer to calculate the page numbers in your increment function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your increment function you can calculate the maximum number of pages and construct your if condition like

```
  if(this.state.currentPage < this.props.contacts.length / this.state.todosPerPage)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add totalPages state to solve this prob

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      characters: [],
      currentPage: 1,
      todosPerPage: 6,
      totalPages: props.contacts / 6
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
Increment/Decrement:

increment=(event)=> {
    if(this.state.currentPage<this.state.totalPages)
    this.setState({
      currentPage: this.state.currentPage+1

    });
  }

  decrement=(event)=> {
    if (this.state.currentPage>1)
    this.setState({
       currentPage: this.state.currentPage-1,
    });
  }
```